# How to create a binary variable from a loop and an if statement

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

Assuming I have a vector `x` containing 20 values between 0 and 2.

```
x = runif(20, 0, 2)
```

Now, I want to create another vector `y` (a binary variable) containing only 0 and 1 on the following condition: `y = 0` if `x < 1` and `y = 1` in case `x > 1`.

I tried to do it with a loop and an `if` statement in the following way:

```
x = runif(20, 0, 2) # Create a vector of 20 values between 0 and 2
y = rep(5, 20) # Create a vector of 20 values (only 5's)

for(i in 1:length(x)) # Loop that assigns values to the y vector depending on x
{
  if(x < 1)
  {
    y[i] = 0
  }
  else
  {
    y[i] = 1
  }
}
```

But it unfortunately did not work as planned as my `y` vector ends up containing 0's only. What did I do wrong? Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done using vectorized operations instead of a loop:

```
> x <- runif(20, 0, 2)
> y <- as.integer(x > 1)
> x
 [1] 0.06553935 1.23221386 0.39982502 0.27821193 1.15281280 0.14248373 0.09206153 1.63555223 0.44962775 0.70711450
[11] 0.93994130 1.41955732 1.95790383 0.99646643 1.38737559 1.75813075 1.32844540 0.53076589 0.96152349 1.31173062
> y
 [1] 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1
```

A more general solution is to use `ifelse` as it would allow you to use values other than zero and one:

```
> ifelse(x <= 1, -5, 5)
 [1] -5  5 -5 -5  5 -5 -5  5 -5 -5 -5  5  5 -5  5  5  5 -5 -5  5
```

Finally, it is worth noting that you can use more complex expressions with either of the two approaches:

```
> ifelse(x >= .5 & x <= 1.5, -5, 5)
 [1]  5 -5  5  5 -5  5  5  5  5 -5 -5 -5  5 -5 -5  5 -5 -5 -5 -5
```

Comment: Wow! I love R even more!!! Thank you very much @NPE. However, what would I do if I wanted to assign values other than 0 and 1?

Comment: @SavedByJESUS: You could use `ifelse`, e.g. `ifelse(x > 1, 5, -5)`

Comment: @NPE -- or, for fun, this: `c(-5, 5)[(x>1) + 1]`

Comment: Is there anyway to create a trichotomous variable (0, 1 and 2) with vectorized operations? Thank you very much once again!

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I must admit that I do not really understand the code even though it works!

Comment: @SavedByJESUS: `ifelse(x < 2./3, 0, ifelse(x < 4./3, 1, 2))`.

Comment: @NPE very well understood, Sir/Madam! I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @SavedByJESUS -- To see what's going on, try `FALSE + 1; TRUE + 1; c(-5,5)[c(1,2,2,2,1)]`. (Definitely a bit obfuscated, but the idea can be useful.)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I'll try it right away. Thank you so much! R is really awesome!